# Use SSRS lookup function in Visual Studio 2008 Business Intelligence Development Studio with SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm using SSRS with SQL Server 2008 R2 which supposedly should give me an option to use the lookup function so I can use datasets from multiple datasources. My formula is:

```
=Lookup(Fields!ORDERID.Value, Fields!INTERTOURREF.Value, Fields!DLVNAME.Value, "dsAX")
```

The lookup in my formula gives a squiggly red line and a 'name lookup is not declared' error which give me the idea that it might not work with VS 2008.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the formula you are using?

Comment: =Lookup(Fields!ORDERID.Value, Fields!INTERTOURREF.Value, Fields!DLVNAME.Value, "dsAX")

Comment: Used VS 2008 version 9.0.30729.4462 with SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) version 10.50.2550 to test with no error. Maybe you can check the VS and SQL versions you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Lookup` function was only added with Sql Server 2008 **R2** and the original Sql Server 2008 (prior to R2) doesn't have it so you will get that error.

It sounds like you are not on Sql Server 2008 **R2**.

Comment: Hi Chris, we are using R2 / just upgraded. That's why I was eager to try the lookup :)

Comment: Did you re-install Business Intelligence Development Studio?

Comment: Great, glad you got it sorted